# Randomise array of numbers with disqualifying conditions

Tags: php, random, sequence

I wish to create an array with random sequences that correspond to my conditions.

1. The sequence should be composed of 8 different numbers from 1-8.
2. **I should not have more than 2 successive numbers in the first 4 or last 4 numbers. Ex: 1,2,3 is not good nor 5,3,4** because they are successive if sorted (3,4,5).

This is a good example: 1,4,5,7, | 8,6,3,2

This is NOT a good example: 1,3,2,6, | 5,7,8,4 because 1,3,2 are successive numbers if sorted (1,2,3) in the first 4 digits

I made this:

```
         $sequences = array();
    while(count($sequences) < 100){

        //Random 8 numbers sequence from 1-8
         $sequence = array();  
    while(count($sequence) < 8){
            $rand = rand(1,8);
      if(!in_array($rand, $sequence)){
            array_push($sequence, $rand);
         }
      }

        //Insert if numbers are not successive. 
        //Struggling here
        if(?????){
            array_push($sequences, $sequence);
        }
    }
           print_r($sequences);
```

It's working for the generation part of it but I can't figure how to insert sequences that do not contain successive numbers. Any thoughts?

Comment: So...you just want to scramble the list of 1-8?

Comment: @JohnP a made an edit. The numbers in the first 4 or last 4 digit should not be successive in any order. So it's not only scrambled because this 1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4 would not work because 1,2,3 are successive in the first 4 digits.

Comment: In your "NOT good example" of 1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4 - I don't see how 1,3,2 are successive. What do you mean by successive?

Comment: If you are doctoring the results then it isn't random

Comment: @AlvinLee I meant any combinations of 3 numbers that could form a set or +-1. 2,3,1 or 4,6,5 or 1,3,2 for example.

Comment: @Dale Indeed, that might not be a good usage of the term "random"

Comment: I see that you've edited your original question. Do you still consider 8,1,2 to be successive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent the two groups of digits as a 1 or 0 and pick which elements go in each set by picking one of the 8 bit binary strings with four 1s and 0s and no sequences of 3 consecutive 1s or 0s. Each of these binary strings representes by one of the following integers:

```
 43  45  51  53  54  75  77  83  85  86  89  90 101 102 105 106 108
147 149 150 153 154 165 166 169 170 172 178 180 201 202 204 210 212
```

The second half are all symmetric with the first half, so we can just pick a number from the first half and then do some processing to pick the whole set:

```
$combinations = array(43,45,51,53,54,75,77,83,85,86,89,90,101,102,105,106,108);

// Pick a random combination
$combination = $combinations[array_rand($combinations)];
if (mt_rand() & 1)
    $combination = 255 - $combination;  
$combination = str_split(str_pad(decbin($combination), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

// Get the first four values
$first = array_keys(array_filter($combination, function($x){ return $x == '0'; }));
shuffle($first); // Permute them

// Get the last four values
$last = array_keys(array_filter($combination, function($x){ return $x == '1'; }));
shuffle($last); // Permute them

$result = array_map(function($x){ return $x + 1; }, array_merge($first, $last));
```

This will a random sequence with your constraints uniformly at random and should be quite efficient. Some sample outputs:

```
[6, 2, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 8, 7]
[6, 3, 1, 8, 2, 4, 5, 7]
[5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 3]
[5, 2, 8, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4]
[8, 6, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5]
[7, 1, 5, 4, 8, 3, 2, 6]
[5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 8, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 5, 3, 8, 4, 6]
[5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 7, 4, 1]
```

Comment: You're welcome @Wistar.  I'll probably add some more explanation when I get home. Would you find it useful to have code which generates all 19584 sequences with that constraint?

Comment: @Paulpro That might be useful for future viewers of this question if it's not too much work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an ineffective way (in terms of resources) and could be more considered as a hack, but;

```
$sequence = array(1,2,4,5,8,9,5,7);
    usort($sequence, function($a, $b) {
        //if $a + 1 = $b, then $b + 1;
        return ($a + 1) == $b ? $b = $b + 1 : 1;
    });

print_r($sequence);
```

This would return;

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 8 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 [4] => 4 [5] => 9 [6] => 5 [7] => 7 )
```

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear in my question at first but the sequence cannot contain a set of three numbers that are successive in the first 4 or last for digit. This should apply even if the number right across each other.

This is a good example: 1,4,5,7,8,6,3,2 
This is NOT a good example: 1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4 because 1,2,3 are successive in the first 4 digits

Comment: In your good example `1,4,5,7,8,6,3,2` - 4,5 is successive, but you said it's a good example. What does successive mean to you?

Comment: I meant three numbers that would be successive if sorted in the first 4 or last 4 digits.

If I sort the first 4 and last 4 of 1,4,5,7,8,6,3,2. I'd have 1,4,5,7 and 2,3,6,8. I don't have 3 successive numbers in the first 4 nor the last 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a beautiful code, I could shorten it but still, it's working.

```
    $sequence = array();
    $sequences = array();
    $loops = 0;

    while($loops < 10000){
        $loops++;
        //Get a sequence
        while(count($sequence) < 8){
            $rand = rand(1,8);
            if(!in_array($rand, $sequence)){
                array_push($sequence, $rand);
            }
        }

        //Checks if sequence meet requirements
        //This part could be summarized in a function
        $first = array($sequence[0], $sequence[1], $sequence[2],$sequence[3]);
        $last = array($sequence[4], $sequence[5], $sequence[6],$sequence[7]);

        sort($first);
        sort($last);

        if($first[1] != $first[0]+1 || $first[1] !=$first[2]-1){
            if($first[2] != $first[1]+1 || $first[2] !=$first[3]-1){
                if($last[1] != $last[0]+1 || $last[1] !=$last[2]-1){
                    if($last[2] != $last[1]+1 || $last[2] !=$last[3]-1){

                        $sequence = array_merge($first, $last);
                        if(!in_array($sequence, $sequences)){
                            array_push($sequences, $sequence);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $sequence = array();        
    }
    print_r($sequences);
```